# How do I clear the text in a Label with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I'm new to python and I'm making this rock paper scissors game with tkinter. I have a problem with clearing the text that says if have won or lost after you play one time. I tried doing it with `destroy()`, but I can't get it to work. The issue is that when you choose rock paper or scissors for the first time it works, but the every next game you play it overwrites the old score.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()

#Functions
def Rock():
    user = "r"
    
    computer = random.choice(['r', 'p', 's'])

    if user == computer:
        UsedLabel = Label(root, text="You Tied!") 
        UsedLabel.grid(row=2 , column=1)

    if is_win(user, computer):
        UsedLabel = Label(root, text="You Have Won!")
        UsedLabel.grid(row=2 , column=1)

    else:  
        UsedLabel = Label(root, text="You Lost!")
        UsedLabel.grid(row=2 , column=1)

def Paper():
    user = "p"

    computer = random.choice(['r', 'p', 's'])

    if user == computer:
        UsedLabel = Label(root, text="You Tied!") 
        UsedLabel.grid(row=2 , column=1)

    if is_win(user, computer):
        UsedLabel = Label(root, text="You Have Won!")
        UsedLabel.grid(row=2 , column=1)
    
    else:
        UsedLabel = Label(root, text="You Lost!")
        UsedLabel.grid(row=2 , column=1)


def Scissors():
    user = "s"
    
    computer = random.choice(['r', 'p', 's'])

    if user == computer:
        UsedLabel = Label(root, text="You Tied!") 
        UsedLabel.grid(row=2 , column=1)

    if is_win(user, computer):
        UsedLabel = Label(root, text="You Have Won!")
        UsedLabel.grid(row=2 , column=1)

    else:
        UsedLabel = Label(root, text="You Lost!")
        UsedLabel.grid(row=2 , column=1)

#def iswin
def is_win(player, opponent):
    if (player == 'r' and opponent == 's') or (player == 's' and opponent == 'p') or (player == 'p' and opponent == 'r'):
        return True

# Main Label
MainLabel = Label(root, text="Rock Paper or Scissors? Chose one!")

MainLabel.grid(row=0, column=1)

#Buttons
RockB = Button(root, text="    Rock!    ", padx=20, pady=10, command=Rock)
PaperB = Button(root, text="    Paper!    ", padx=20, pady=10, command=Paper)
ScissorsB = Button(root, text="    Scissors!    ", padx=20, pady=10, command=Scissors)

ScissorsB.grid(row=1, column=2)
PaperB.grid(row=1, column=1)
RockB.grid(row=1, column=0)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `label_instance.config(text='')` or `label_instance['text'] = ''` and you don't need to create a label each time, you are fine if you just have one label also: I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Improved your code a bit:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button
import random


player_wins = {'rs', 'pr', 'sp'}
player_draws = {'rr', 'pp', 'ss'}


def choose(choice):
    computer = random.choice(['r', 'p', 's'])
    combo = choice + computer

    if combo in player_wins:
        text = 'You won!'
    elif combo in player_draws:
        text = 'You drew!'
    else:
        text = 'You lost!'

    game_state.config(text=text)
    
    # this sets label's text to empty after about 1 second
    root.after(1000, lambda: game_state.config(text=''))


root = Tk()

# Main Label
title = Label(root, text="Rock, Paper or Scissors? Chose one!")
title.grid(row=0, column=1)

# Buttons
rock_btn = Button(root, text="Rock!", padx=20, pady=10, command=lambda: choose('r'))
paper_btn = Button(root, text="Paper!", padx=20, pady=10, command=lambda: choose('p'))
scissors_btn = Button(root, text="Scissors!", padx=20, pady=10, command=lambda: choose('s'))

scissors_btn.grid(row=1, column=2)
paper_btn.grid(row=1, column=1)
rock_btn.grid(row=1, column=0)

game_state = Label(root)
game_state.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3)

root.mainloop()
```

First of you don't need separate functions for each user choice, you are fine with just one, just pass an argument, you can still use a bunch of `if/elif` to check for user choice against the computer choice but I used a set to do that a bit easier and to make it more compact.

The main part is that after 1 second the label gets cleared using the scheduled function which was scheduled using `.after()` method

Important: I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

I also suggest that you follow PEP 8 and use `snake_case` for variable and function names and `CapitalCase` for class names

Also if you want to have inside space for the widgets you can use the `ipadx` and `ipady` options but it seems that you want to actually expand those widgets to their maximum, for that the simplest in this case it to add `sticky='nsew'` to each `.grid()` method

Sources:

- [Some info about `.after()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-after-method-in-tkinter/)

Comment: Thank you for this thorough answer. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

To clean up a label you can use

```
label_name.config(text="")
```

Comment: AFAIK, `Label` does not have `delete` method

Comment: @AFAIK My mistake. I had confused with canvas where it would be. `label_name.delete(0, tk.END)`